# Mongoimport JSON file error: "BSON representation of supplied JSON array is too large: code FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds"

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm trying to import my json file to a db using the following command:

```
mongoimport --db db_name --collection collection_name file.json --jsonArray
```

But it's not working, and I'm getting this error:

```
Tue Oct 21 15:42:20.176 check 0 0
Tue Oct 21 15:42:20.176 imported 0 objects
Tue Oct 21 15:42:20.176 ERROR: encountered 1 error(s)
```

I'm using MongoDB 2.4.9. What can I try next?

### Edit

Adding `-vvvv` to the command results in the following:

```
Tue Oct 21 16:02:48.582 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Oct 21 16:02:48.583 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Tue Oct 21 16:02:48.584 connected connection!
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Tue Oct 21 16:02:48.584 ns: ip.ip_data
Tue Oct 21 16:02:48.585 filesize: 3526
Tue Oct 21 16:02:48.585 User Assertion: 13293:BSON representation of supplied JSON array is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds: offset:211
```

Comment: mongoimport isn't very informative. Try adding `-vvvvv` to the commandline to see if gives some more information.

Comment: I've never tried this command before but I did now and added the result as an Edit to the original question.

Comment: The BSON produced from the JSON can't be larger than 16MB. What does the JSON look like? Are you sure you want to use `--jsonArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using [`jsonArray`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--jsonArray) the total array size must be less than 16MiB, or you will get that error.  You are effectively doing a bulk insert where a single document containing an array is sent as an insert, the server interprets this as an insert per array element, but the total can't be larger than the [largest permissible BSON document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size).

If you break it up into smaller arrays and import those you will be OK, or you could use a bit of code to unwind the array and just do a straight import with the result.